# Is trying to understand spammer behavior on topic?

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask a question "Why would spammers make fake accounts?", asking why spammers appear to be dedicated to making accounts on a site where accounts are private.

Would a question like this be on topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, no.

There is the obvious answer - for money, whether directly or indirectly driving traffic - but this isn't a security related question as per the site scope..

Comment: This particular question aside - aren't spam-related questions generally accepted here? You make it sound a bit like spam is categorically off-topic.

Comment: Generally, questions asking how to defeat spam are often in scope, but there are a lot of bad questions on this topic. So we treat each one as it comes in.

Comment: Isn't "understanding the behaviour of the enemy" on topic? I have no strong opinion on this, though.

Comment: In circumstances where it is relevant, sure, and there is a more canonical post somewhere here on what Adobe spammy posts could do. But a) everyone knows spammers spam and b) knowing why doesn't change the defence